Black Screen on First Load Before Splash Screen Appears
Image:

first
second

Platform: Android
I'm using "react-native-bootsplash": "^6.2.2" for my splash screen in a React Native app. On the initial load, the screen shows a black background with the splash screen image briefly, and then it switches to the normal splash screen (a white background with the same image) as defined in my code.
I'm not sure why the app shows a black screen first before loading the correct splash screen. What might be causing this issue, and how can I fix it?

Environment info

System:
  OS: Windows 11 10.0.22631
  CPU: "(4) x64 AMD Ryzen 3 4300U with Radeon Graphics         "
  Memory: 9.18 GB / 19.37 GB
Binaries:
  Node:
    version: 20.14.0
    path: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
  Yarn: Not Found
  npm:
    version: 10.7.0
    path: C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
  Watchman: Not Found
SDKs:
  Android SDK:
    API Levels:
      - "29"
      - "30"
      - "31"
      - "32"
      - "33"
      - "34"
      - "35"
    Build Tools:
      - 30.0.2
      - 30.0.3
      - 33.0.0
      - 33.0.1
      - 34.0.0
      - 35.0.0
    System Images:
      - android-30 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom
      - android-33 | Google APIs Intel x86_64 Atom
      - android-35 | Google APIs Intel x86_64 Atom
    Android NDK: Not Found
  Windows SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
  Android Studio: AI-232.10300.40.2321.11668458
  Visual Studio: Not Found
Languages:
  Java: javac 17
  Ruby: Not Found
npmPackages:
  "@react-native-community/cli": Not Found
  react:
    installed: 18.2.0
    wanted: 18.2.0
  react-native:
    installed: 0.74.6
Android:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false
iOS:
  hermesEnabled: Not found
  newArchEnabled: Not found


App.tsx

import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import type {PropsWithChildren} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  useColorScheme,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

import BootSplash from 'react-native-bootsplash';

type SectionProps = PropsWithChildren<{
  title: string;
}>;

function Section({children, title}: SectionProps): React.JSX.Element {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';
  return (
    <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
      <Text
        style={[
          styles.sectionTitle,
          {
            color: isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
          },
        ]}>
        {title}
      </Text>
      <Text
        style={[
          styles.sectionDescription,
          {
            color: isDarkMode ? Colors.light : Colors.dark,
          },
        ]}>
        {children}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function App(): React.JSX.Element {
  useEffect(() => {
    const init = async () => {
      // …do multiple sync or async tasks
    };

    init().finally(async () => {
      await BootSplash.hide({fade: true});
      console.log('BootSplash has been hidden successfully');
    });
  }, []);

  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';

  const backgroundStyle = {
    backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.darker : Colors.lighter,
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={backgroundStyle}>
      <StatusBar
        barStyle={isDarkMode ? 'light-content' : 'dark-content'}
        backgroundColor={backgroundStyle.backgroundColor}
      />
      <ScrollView
        contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
        style={backgroundStyle}>
        <Header />
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
          }}>
          <Section title="Step One">
            Edit <Text style={styles.highlight}>App.tsx</Text> to change this
            screen and then come back to see your edits.
          </Section>
          <Section title="See Your Changes">
            <ReloadInstructions />
          </Section>
          <Section title="Debug">
            <DebugInstructions />
          </Section>
          <Section title="Learn More">
            Read the docs to discover what to do next:
          </Section>
          <LearnMoreLinks />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  sectionContainer: {
    marginTop: 32,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
  },
  sectionDescription: {
    marginTop: 8,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '400',
  },
  highlight: {
    fontWeight: '700',
  },
});

export default App;


AndroidManifest.xml

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

  <application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
      android:launchMode="singleTask"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
      android:exported="true"
      android:theme="@style/BootTheme">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>


MainActivity.kt

package com.rnbootsplash

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.fabricEnabled
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactActivityDelegate

import android.os.Bundle
import com.zoontek.rnbootsplash.RNBootSplash

class MainActivity : ReactActivity() {
  
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    RNBootSplash.init(this, R.style.BootTheme) // ⬅️ initialize the splash screen
    super.onCreate(null) // or super.onCreate(null) with react-native-screens
  }

  /**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
   * rendering of the component.
   */
  override fun getMainComponentName(): String = "RnBootsplash"

  /**
   * Returns the instance of the [ReactActivityDelegate]. We use [DefaultReactActivityDelegate]
   * which allows you to enable New Architecture with a single boolean flags [fabricEnabled]
   */
  override fun createReactActivityDelegate(): ReactActivityDelegate =
      DefaultReactActivityDelegate(this, mainComponentName, fabricEnabled)
}


colors.xml

<resources>
    <color name="bootsplash_background">#ffffff</color>
</resources>

I already try clear metro & gradle cache, still not work.
Edit: I believe this is an error on some devices, so how to solve it?

Try add this to styles.xml in android/app/src/main/res/value/styles.xml
<style...>
<!-- ... Other settings -->
     <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
...
</style>


Hi, still not solved.

Try add this to styles.xml in android/app/src/main/res/value/styles.xml
<style...>
<!-- ... Other settings -->
     <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
...
</style>

This fix works for me.
Dec 18, 2024

This answer has already been given.
